# How to pretend to browse from a different country?

Tags: internet, proxy

How to pretend to browse from a different country for view Streaming Online Television From Another Country or to use programms that don't work in my country or to Buying (shop).

Edit:
The best solution until now (11/2012)I thing, is to use the add-on [AnonymoX](http://www.anonymox.net/en) with firefox.

Comment: -1 What you are asking is likely to be illegal.

Comment: -1, not specific to Ubuntu at all.

Comment: @Joao It's not illegal, there is nothing about an ip address and where it says it's from that is considered fraud. Proxing is a legal and important part of net neutrality.

Comment: Not illegal for sure. Depending on the answer, it may be Ubuntu specific (OS specific, GNU/Linux specific...) as well. For me, important and nice question.

Comment: Using a proxy is not illegal, deliberately circumventing a validation mechanism to get access to a service you are not entitled to, is.

Comment: this isn't a specific ubuntu thing... get a proxy or vpn....

Comment: We are not lawyers.

Comment: I hate people that say something is illegal having no idea if it's illegal in somebody else's country

Answer (score 7):

you can use *tor proxy* to browse internet anonymously. Check this link for more info:
http://maketecheasier.com/install-tor-in-ubuntu/2010/07/06

Answer (score 5):

Vassilis, in order for your computer to be registered in another country you will need a computer in that country. For instance watching the BBC iPlayer can be done by having a computer in UK and paying the TV license (obviously). It helps if you're a resident who is visiting abroad as a home address makes this easier.

The best method I've found of using a proxy is the ssh tunnel method which is documented here: http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/12/08/ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-forwarding-secure-browsing/

This assumes you have a computer in the target country of course.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Firefox you can go to Add-ons - Extensions and download and install an [extension Hola Better Internet](https://hola.org/) and after it is installed you will see its icon in the upper right corner. Click on it and choose country you want to vpn to. Done.

Comment: I find it in crhome to.

Comment: DON'T USE HOLA BETTER INTERNET / HOLA UNBLOCKER / HOLA INTERNET ACCELERATOR (sorry for the caps, but it's  REALLY important that you DO NOT use it). More information here: [Adios, Hola! - Why you should immediately uninstall Hola](http://adios-hola.org/)

Comment: very odd: "When a user installs Hola, he becomes a VPN endpoint, and other users of the Hola network may exit through his internet connection and take on his IP." (more [here](https://8ch.net/hola.html))

Answer (score 2):

In short, your internet connection IP address already identifies you to a specific country. In order to look like you are coming from another country, you need to contact another computer in the country you want to be seen as, and FROM THIS computer, launch the actual connection to the targeted service. The service has to see that the source IP address is from the right country.

Usually, this means that you either use a service such as TOR that will redirect your connections from all over the world, or have a computer in the right country, that you can completely control, or at least that you control enough to launch another connection from it. TOR might be your best bet.

Comment: Is the Tor, https://www.torproject.org/?

Answer (score 2):

Using the proxy server, You can pretend as acting from different countries like Japan, Canada, USA etc.. It helps to change my IP and also hiding the original IP address by showing a fake IP address. This makes to view the online television streaming from any country or use any programs like Buying (shop) etc.. To check your Network IP address, visit the site [IP-details.com](http://www.ip-details.com) .