# How to access blocked sites?

Tags: proxy

I am in Pakistan and [YouTube](http://www.YouTube.com) is blocked here. I want to take the Lecture videos from YouTube. In Windows, I was using [Hotspotshield](http://www.hotspotshield.com) to bypass the proxy.

But now, using Ubuntu, I don't know how to bypass the proxy. I found some where that i can bypass the proxy by using putty software. Can you guide me how can I bypass proxy by that? I tried, but I was not able to do so. Kindly tell me some easy method to bypass proxy. I don't want to used websites like accesstoblockedsites.com.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/11789/how-to-pretend-to-browse-from-a-different-country

Comment: You can use Tor browser. https://www.torproject.org/download/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WARNING**:

You will be hard-pressed to find good free proxy and VPN services. That's because at its core, no free service can truly be free. In one form or another there will always be some form of a business model behind it. And in the case of free proxy networks and VPNs the provider's income might fully well depend on selling your data to third parties. So please be wary when using the services below.

---

You could use a free VPN service. It's pretty easy to set up:

> - Open Network Manager – From the desktop click on the Network Manager    icon in the top right hand corner, click on VPN Connections and
>   Configure VPN. If you can’t see the Network Manager icon, you can
>   open network manager by clicking on System > Preferences > Network
>   Configuration and then click on the VPN tab.
> - Add VPN connection – When the VPN Connection window is displayed,    click on Add to create the new connection.
> - Choose the connection type – Ensure the connection type is PPTP and    click Create. Enter VPN Account Details – For gateway enter
>   “xx.justfreevpn.com” as the VPN server name. In the Connection name
>   field, enter “xx.justfreevpn.com” as the new connection name. Enter
>   VPN username and VPN password too.
> - Advanced Settings – Select both MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2 options. Check    the box labeled Use Point to Point encryption (MPPE) and then click
>   OK. Click OK again to save the VPN connection.
> - Connect to the VPN – Now start the VPN connection by clicking on the    Network Manager Icon again, select VPN Connections and click on
>   the    new connection you have created.
> - You’re connected! – The Network Manager icon should now have a little    padlock icon on it to indicate that the VPN is now
>   connected.

Source: [JustFreeVPN | Setup Howto *(archived)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20180706031252/http://www.justfreevpn.com/how-to-setup-free-vpn/)

---

A comparison of paid VPN services and their privacy policies may be found at:
[Which VPN Providers Really Take Anonymity Seriously in 2020? | TorrentFreak](https://torrentfreak.com/vpn-services-that-take-your-anonymity-seriously-2013-edition-130302/)

Comment: You are welcome, mate. I just hope the governments of the world will one day learn that censoring the internet makes no sense.

Comment: This is great, but I coyuldn't find out who are the people behind this service... or why they do provide the service... or any statement about their privacy policy... Any info ?

Comment: Couldn't find any official privacy policy but this [forum post](http://justfreevpn.forumotion.com/t1-yes-we-provide-just-free-vpn-service#1) makes it quite clear that you should be careful when using ths VPN as any illegal activity (probably illegal as defined by the jurisdiction of the country the VPN servers are located in) could get reported to the authorities. As for account details, etc., just make sure that you are connected through HTTPS. You can force HTTPS connections with this [addon](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) by the EFF.