# I need a good solution to bypass internet censorship on Ubuntu

Tags: proxy, vpn

I live in Iran, where  many websites are blocked from access by a professional local firewall.
I'm looking for a free  VPN, HTTPS, or any possible proxy software/solution for Ubuntu that could let me to bypass the censorship, so that I could at least access Facebook and Twitter.
I'm saying free because I'm a full time college student and I really can't afford buying a VPN service alongside of other costs to just be able to access Facebook and Twitter.
I do use Hotspot Shield  for Windows, which is very fast and does the job. But for Ubuntu OS, I couldn't manage to find a good solution.
I have tried Tor also, but Tor is very, very slow. I can't even open a webpage without waiting for more than  5-10 minutes.

If you know any good and fast solution for bypassing censorship on Ubuntu, please let me know. I can't wait to browse all kinds of pages that I want in Ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: Does Tor work from where you are?

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195952/how-to-access-blocked-sites There are free vpn services in there. Outside AU source: http://en.flossmanuals.net/bypassing-censorship/ch026_air-vpn/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help googling users

this vpn server cuts through iran's firewall like a butter, so if you''ve got a vps or a friend to help you out, it's the best 
Soft Ether VPN:
http://www.softether.org/

client (that works on Linux too):
VPNGate
http://vpngate.net

you can make a Linuxbox free of censorship with soft ether VPN. this was the only stable and fast solution that I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I would use wine to run FireFox and FreeGate :)

http://www.internetfreedom.org/FreeGate

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

Just switch FireFox's proxy to the ip/port listed in the FreeGate application!

Comment: Well if I wanted to do that I basicly reinstall windows on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://usproxy.at and http://stealthproxy.eu I know that those are not blocked from Iran

Comment: welp, those are blocked too