# Setting up a VPN in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vpn

What is the easiest way to set up a VPN in Ubuntu?

I asked this last time but nobody responded, please help, it's really killing me.

I just want a VPN like Hotspot Shield, that masks my IP and outgoing connections

Comment: I posted this the other day: http://askubuntu.com/questions/539027/setting-vpn-in-ubuntu-14-04/539031?noredirect=1#comment737416_539031 I have 25+ companies using VPNs; out of these I can get 22 working on Ubuntu. The other 3 I have not a clue why not though :P

Comment: What kind of VPN? How is your network organized? Is it global or internal only?

Answer (score 0):

Hotspot Shield is an application which connects to U.S.-based VPN servers.

Ubuntu is able to connect both to PPTP and OpenVPN servers natively. If you know the login details of a specific server, you (probably) will be able to connect to it and we will be able to point you to the corresponding guides.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally I get a constructive response, yaaaay.

Is there a guide to OpenVPN somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there is: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openvpn.html#openvpn-simple-client-configuration
But I suggest just installing OpenVPN with "sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn" and then using the GUI. After installing, you should be able to add an OpenVPN connection in your network manager. But depending on your use case, PPTP can be the easier option... (If you think my answer was good enough, please mark it as correct ;) )